# VSCode kill terminal shortcut stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

[image]

It used to work, but it stopped after some of the updates. 1.24.0 is my current version, on Windows 10. Prolblem persists even with no extensions enabled. Ideas?

Comment: Check if you have assigned another action to the same shortcut or perhaps deleted this shortcut below (`"command": "-workbench.action.terminal.kill"`).